# Do-while and Exception Hadnling

Tags: java, exception, do-while

```
package learnjava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class exception {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x =1;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Input first number : ");
            int n1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Input second number : ");
            int n2 = input.nextInt();
            int sum = n1 / n2;
            System.out.println("result = "+sum);
            x = 2;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");

        }

    } while (x == 1);

     }
 }
```

I watched java tutorials in thenewboston.....
I want ask you...why x=2...?can you explain why?...thanks

Comment: so that the loop will break, not very good code if it needs to be explained.  Better to to use useful variable names

Comment: what is the question? You set x to 2 via `x=2` and now you ask why x is 2?

Comment: when user enter all correct integer inputs then you don't want to ask user repeatedly to enter some thing, so loop will be break when `x!=1`

Comment: If you've seen a tutorial that advocates writing code that looks like this, then I would suggest switching to a different tutorial.

Comment: Ugg. Java has the `Boolean` type and it should be used here. I'd suspect the quality of the tutorials you are using if that's some of their sample code!

Comment: He explained that in this second: [Java Programming Tutorial - 82 - Exception Handling](https://youtu.be/K_-3OLkXkzY?t=417)

Comment: @AKSW...yes..i just learning to understanding from youtube....

Answer (score 0):

This a code doesn't approach it's own concept well. 
Nonetheless Do-While is a exit control loop and is keeps on executing the loop till x is not equal to any number except 1. That is if there is any change in x apart from being 'x = 1'then the loop would break as in the loop will stop functioning. Here we are using a try catch to prevent any number being divided by zero and we use x=2 to execute the loop once and exit.

Anyway this is concept builder, but this is not how one would approach this methodology.

Answer (score 0):

do-while loop executes once without checking the condition.
In this case the condition to continue while loop is `x == 1` . That is because you have set `x = 1` in your code above.

While executing prior to checking the condition, using the scanner, you read 2 integers and done some operations on them and printed the result.
As the logic expects flow to stop here (that is just reading 2 integers and printing result), x has been set to 2 that is `x = 2`.

Now answering your question why `x = 2`. **It can be anything other than 1** which will terminate the while loop and not allow any further iterations.

Answer (score 0):

this code do division if you inter the n2 value to 0, exception happened and printed the **error** and the `x=1` value was not changed the while condition is  true **and your code running again** and want the input. if your input was true `(n2!=0)` your operation done and the x value changed to two `x=2`. when the while condition checked the result is false and break the do while loop.
**I write some comment in your code.**

```
package learnjava; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exception {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x =1;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Input first number : ");
            int n1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Input second number : ");
            int n2 = input.nextInt();
            int sum = n1 / n2;//if your n2 input was 0 exception happened and go to catch block.
            System.out.println("result = "+sum);
            x = 2;// if one time your code execute without exception the x changed to 2. if exception happened your code execute again.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");

        }

    } while (x == 1);

     }
 }
```

Comment: @WildanAlifR In this case, loop will continue till it encounters error and then quits the loop as `x=2` is coded in catch

Comment: @WildanAlifR if your input (n2==0) exception happened and the do -while break. else continue again the do-while.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple,

The do while works this way.

First the do part gets executes, if the condition in the while loop is satisfied, the do loop executes again. This will go on, till the condition in the while loop is not satisfied.

```
 do {
       //work is done. 
       //now lets us change the condition so that we can get out of this do-while loop. 
       // this condition is nothing but setting x equal to nay value other than 1. It can be 2 or 10000 or -1.
    } while (x == 1);
```

So here once the functionlity of the do loop is satisfied, the x==2 is done. This makes sure that the condition in while is not satisfied and hence the code exists do-while loop.